# Spatial and temporal dimensions orthogonality

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, metric-tensor, time, spacetime-dimensions

It seems that the spatial dimensions are orthogonal: a particle can move along one axis without changing its position in relation to other two axes.

It seems that the temporal dimension is somewhat orthogonal:

- a particle can move along the time axis but not along the space axes by standing still
- if a particle is to move along space axes, it necessarily also moves along time axis

Is there something deep and meaningful in this seemingly incomplete orthogonality, or is it just a consequence of some theory (perhaps general relativity)?

If we take into account quantum mechanic, the above statements are not entirely correct. A particle cannot really be standing completely still (due to uncertainty principle). But does it matter?

Do we need to treat massive and massless particles separately in this deliberation?

Answer (score 3):

Relativistically, the right way to construe this notion of orthogonality is in terms of the inner product between four-vectors.

When two spacelike vectors are orthogonal, it means what we have in mind in Euclidean geometry.

When a timelike vector is orthogonal to a spacelike vector, it means that to an observer who is moving along the timelike vector, the spacelike vector is *purely* spatial, i.e., it connects events that are simultaneous.

A lightlike vector is orthogonal to itself.

Answer (score 1):

1. What do you mean by orthogonal dimensions? It is not a well-defined notion. For starters, one doesn't have to draw coordinate axis orthogonal for a coordinate system to serve its purpose of coordinatizing a physical system. Even if one did draw them orthogonal, a [Lorentz transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_transformation) could change that.
2. The lesson to be learned is that we need an objective/physical definition of [orthogonality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonality), that doesn't depend on how we draw it on paper. This is provided by the [metric tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_tensor) or [inner product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product) 
   $$ {\bf u} ~\perp~ {\bf v}\quad \Leftrightarrow \quad g({\bf u} , {\bf v})~=~0.\tag{1}$$ This definition (1) is Lorentz covariant.